# JAVA: How to combine message boxes with multiple outputs

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am learning Java and have a rather simple program that returns a series of numbers in accordance with the [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). I can have it output into the console or have many `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` windows pop up, one with each number in it.

How would I combine the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`'s to show all the outputs in one `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`?

Code:

```
package collatz;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Collatz {

/**
 * Demonstrates the Collatz Cojecture
 * with a randomly generated number
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The randomly generated number was: " + n);


    while(n > 1){
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            n = n / 2;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n);
        }
        else{
            n = 3 * n + 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n);
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done.");

}

}
```

Thanks!

--
ZuluDeltaNiner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of the full string to be displayed, then display it at the end:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);

    StringBuilder output = new StringBUilder("The randomly generated number was: " + n + "\n");

    while(n > 1){
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else{
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
        output.append(n + "\n");
    }

    output.append("Done.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);

}
```

Comment: Better to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) than concatenate to a `String`.

Comment: True, changed to reflect better programming practice.

Comment: Thanks helloworld922 and @Andrew Thompson !